# Preferred backend programming for Android

Tags: android, .net, ios

I am a fresh PHP web developer, however, I'm working on a mobile app startup that will operate on Android. My programming team are highly experienced .NET developers. Is it the right choice to use .NET for the backend development? Is there any OTHER programming language that is better for Android (consider that an iOS version will be developed in the future)?

Comment: It's probably the right choice to use the platform your team knows, unless you're prepared to spend resources cross-training them. As long as the back-end has a vendor-neutral interface, it really doesn't matter what platform is powering it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naturally you should be coding in what you are experienced and productive in. If your team are experienced .NET developers they should be doing .NET. A native mobile application doesn't care what the backend is written in. Its a black box it talks to through APIs. All it cares about is the API and the format chosen for data serialization. .NET developers seem to go for SOAP, which I feel is a bad choice for a mobile application. Way to much overhead in the data payload.

TL;DR
Write the backend in whatever you like, but stick to a simple REST-ish API design with lightweight data serialization like JSON for communication.

Answer (score 0):

I would HIGHLY recommend [MonoDroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) and [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) from [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/). This platform greatly accelerates development and considering that you have a team of .NET developers (and are considering iOS soon) - I can think of no other development path that would give you a greater (development) cost/benefit ratio.

Remember - your code will mostly be portable to Windows 8, too!